# Sql - select to retrieve data in a linked table on if certain data is present

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from a primary table, my_form, and some from a table linked via a linktable.

Here are my three tables:

```
my_form:
# idmy_form, summary, description, station
'1', 'OSR puncture', 'Puncture while driving to work', 'Thornbury'
'2', 'Windscreen wiper broke', 'Wiper broke while going shopping', 'Bristol'
'3', 'Out of screenwash', 'Run out of screen wash en route to Cardiff', 'Cardiff'


form_action:
# idmy_form, action_id
'1', '201'
'1', '202'
'1', '203'
'2', '301'
'2', '302'
'3', '401'
'3', '402'
'3', '403'
'3', '404'
'3', '405'

actions:
# action_id, action_detail, action_required, action_date
'201', 'Fix', 'Open', '2013-01-01 00:00:00'
'202', 'Fix', 'Amend', '2013-01-04 00:00:00'
'203', 'Fix', 'Close', '2013-01-06 00:00:00'
'301', 'Fix', 'Open', '2013-03-01 00:00:00'
'302', 'Fix', 'Review', '2013-04-12 00:00:00'
'401', 'Fix', 'Open', '2013-09-04 00:00:00'
'402', 'Fix', 'Review', '2013-09-12 00:00:00'
'403', 'Fix', 'Close', '2013-09-17 00:00:00'
'404', 'Fix', 'Reopen', '2013-09-21 00:00:00'
'405', 'Fix', 'Close', '2013-09-23 00:00:00'
```

So far the sql I have is this:

```
SELECT mf.idmy_form, mf.summary, mf.station, fa.action_id, act.action_required, act.action_date 
FROM CarAngel.my_form mf
INNER JOIN form_action fa ON mf.idmy_form = fa.idmy_form
LEFT OUTER JOIN actions act ON fa.action_id = act.action_id
WHERE act.action_required = 'Close';
```

This outputs the following, obviously my where clause is restricting the records retrieved:

```
# idmy_form, summary, station, action_id, action_required, action_date
'1', 'OSR puncture', 'Thornbury', '203', 'Close', '2013-01-06 00:00:00'
'3', 'Out of screenwash', 'Cardiff', '403', 'Close', '2013-09-17 00:00:00'
```

I think I am struggling to use the right join type as I want every row from the primary my_form table returned and to also include one matching action record only if the record has action.action_required = 'Close'.

Otherwise I want the record from my_form, but the action data just returned as a null for the my_form records where there is no associated action record with an action_required = 'Close'.

** Update

The only way I could get this to work myself was with the sql below.  However this didn't work when used in a database view.

```
SELECT idmy_form, summary, station, 
    (SELECT actions.action_date FROM actions WHERE actions.action_required = 'Close'
        AND actions.action_id = 
        (SELECT form_action.action_id 
            FROM form_action WHERE form_action.idmy_form = my_form.idmy_form
            AND form_action.action_id = actions.action_id))
AS action_date
FROM my_form;
```

jpw solution below works great.  So question answered, thanks.

** One further query what if the datasets are amended as above to have multiple actions record with action_required = 'Close' related to one header record in the my_form table.
This would give the following returned data:

```
# idmy_form, summary, station, action_id, action_required, action_date
'1', 'OSR puncture', 'Thornbury', '203', 'Close', '2013-01-06 00:00:00'
'2', 'Windscreen wiper broke', 'Bristol', NULL, NULL, NULL
'3', 'Out of screenwash', 'Cardiff', '403', 'Close', '2013-09-17 00:00:00'
'3', 'Out of screenwash', 'Cardiff', '405', 'Close', '2013-09-23 00:00:00'
```

Is there a way of only retrieving the latest dated action record with the 'Close' action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the result you're looking for is this:

```
idmy_form   summary             station     action_id   action_required action_date
1       OSR puncture            Thornbury   203         Close           2013-01-06 00:00:00.000
2       Windscreen wiper broke  Bristol     NULL        NULL            NULL
3       Out of screenwash       Cardiff     403         Close           2013-09-17 00:00:00.000
```

Then the query you want is this:

```
SELECT 
    mf.idmy_form, 
    mf.summary, 
    mf.station, 
    a.action_id, 
    a.action_required, 
    a.action_date 
FROM my_form mf
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
       act.action_id, 
       act.action_required, 
       act.action_date, 
       fa.idmy_form 
    FROM form_action fa
    JOIN actions act 
     ON fa.action_id = act.action_id 
     AND act.action_required = 'Close'
) a 
ON a.idmy_form = mf.idmy_form
```

If you add a where condition to the left join you effectively eliminate the null values (and make it an implicit inner join), so add the filter to the join condition instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that makes sense.  I have updated my question as I don't require all the records returned.  Just the records as per the update at the bottom of my question.  Any further ideas would be great.  I shall continue to try different options and update if I get the solution.

Comment: @NeilJohnson Sorry it took some time, but I've changed my answer and think it should give you the result you want now.

Comment: Many thanks @jpw, that works fine.  The only other solution I came up with is amended to the end of my question.  Although this didn't work when put in as a database view.

Comment: I have one further query at the bottom of my question.  With the solution from jpw it works fine, but I have come across another scenario.  I am trying to find a solution to only retrieve the latest dated action record for the header table record.  Any additional ideas would be great.

Comment: @NeilJohnson Yes, that would be possible to do, but rather than answering here in a comment I think you should post it as a new question so more people get to see it.